# Оформление элементов списка li

Tags: html, css

Динамически формирую список. В итоге получается что-то вроде:

```css
ul.hr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

ul.hr li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="hr">
    <li>Мчади</li>
    <li>Када на мацони</li>
    <li>Пахлава</li>
    <li>Кчуч</li>
    <li>Лилибдж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы на первой строчке отображалось только 3 элемента li, а на следющей 2 остальных, выровнянных по центру, что-то вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
ul.hr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.hr li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="hr">
    <li>Мчади</li>
    <li>Када на мацони</li>
    <li>Пахлава</li>
    <li id="xx">Кчуч</li>
    <li>Лилибдж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

```css
ul.hr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.hr li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

ul.hr li:last-child {
  margin-left: -33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="hr">
    <li>Мчади</li>
    <li>Када на мацони</li>
    <li>Пахлава</li>
    <li id="xx">Кчуч</li>
    <li>Лилибдж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: я как понял, основную работу делает -webkit-flex-flow? В chrome работает так как нужно, но в IE11 можно как-то тоже заставить также показывать?

Comment: Получилось. Добавил `flex-flow: row wrap;` и заработало в IE.

Comment: все правельно, не заметил... удачи...

Comment: извиняюсь, возможно как-то изменить padding между нижними элементами снизу, сделать их чуть поближе друг к другу. Не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: @S.Ivanov добавил...

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с `display: inline-block;`

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.hr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.hr li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: calc(33.333% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="hr">
    <li>Мчади</li>
    <li>Када на мацони</li>
    <li>Пахлава</li>
    <li>Кчуч</li>
    <li>Лилибдж</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```